# How can I install a GFCI receptacle to provide protection to other devices?

Tags: electrical, wiring, gfci

I currently have in my shop, a 20 amp outlet directly below my panel which is approximately halfway along one of the walls.  Instead of having the GFCI outlet at the end, I would like to replace the existing outlet with a 20 amp GFCI outlet and add regular outlets to the left and to the right of it along that wall. Can I pigtail the black and white wires?  Will the outlets be protected?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, look carefully at a GFI (or equivalently GFCI) [outlet](http://www.casacullen.com/2011/02/diy-how-to-change-a-gfci-wall-outlet.html):

[image]

You can see the terminals at the top are labeled *Line* which means, upstream power.  The pair of terminals at the bottom are labeled *Load*, which means this is where to connect outlets downstream which are protected by this GFI.

Be careful not to bridge the line terminals to the load terminals!  A pigtail should only connect to the *load* terminals.

Comment: @Jose You might also seriously consider pigtailing the wires you connect to the load side, instead of using the stab-in holes on the back, UNLESS they're the type of stab-ins where tightening the screws on the sides of the outlet clamps a plate down onto the wires.